# C# - How to deserialize a datetime with extra information?

Tags: c#, json, datetime, deserialization

I have a system that currently deserializes some objects (with System.Runtime.Serialization) that include a datetime, and want to update it such that the datetimes will now include milliseconds. However, there's a possibility that the incoming JSON strings include the new datetime format with ms before the servers that deserialize have updated, and when testing this scenario locally I get an exception.

E.g. the new datetime format is "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.FFFFFFFK" so in the JSON we'll have a value like "2021-05-04T09:32:44.875", however the old format is "s", so if a machine still using the old format receives a datetime with milliseconds it throws a

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException "String was not
> recognized as a valid DateTime."

Is there any way to tell DataContractJsonSerializer to ignore extra information in the datetime?

Here's a sample test case that reproduces the issue:

```
[DataContract]
private class TestObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime date
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    DataContractJsonSerializerSettings dataContractJsonSerializerSettings =
    new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings
    {
        IgnoreExtensionDataObject = false,
        MaxItemsInObjectGraph = int.MaxValue,
        EmitTypeInformation = EmitTypeInformation.Never,
        DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormat("s") { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces }
    };
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TestObject), dataContractJsonSerializerSettings);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);

    string json = "{\"date\":\"2021-05-04T09:32:44.875\"}";
    streamReader.DiscardBufferedData();
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    memoryStream.SetLength(0);
    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var obj = serializer.ReadObject(memoryStream);
}
```

Comment: You need to write a [custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0) `JsonConverter` to handle that case.

Comment: And you should be using either Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json to do this.